# WSO2 ESB handling servlet response as binary

Tags: servlets, soap, wso2, wso2-esb

I have a soap to rest conversion in my inSecuence, for testing I am using soap-ui as cliente and a servlet developed with eclipse and axis in local. So far so good, everything works fine.

But... when I change the http endpoint to the real servlet i am getting the response as binary

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> 
<soapenv:Body> 
  <axis2ns1073:binary xmlns:axis2ns1073="...">T0z=</axis2ns1073:binary> 
</soapenv:Body> 
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

When I call the servlet with any browser (eg Firefox) using the same url I am getting "NOK"

That means:

- The service is working fine using a local mock
- The service is returning data as binary when invoking to real servlet
- A browser like firefox can handle properly the message when invoking to real servlet

I've used tcpmon to see the differences between the response of the mock and the response of the real servlet. The main difference is that the real servlet is responding with transfer encoding: chunked

¿What could I do to treat the response properly?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Does your servlet has the "Content-Type" header in the response?

As I can see in your attached image the Content-Type header is missing. When Content-Type header is missing in the response, ESB assumes the Content-Type as binary and parse the response as Binary.

So to fix your problem, please update your servlet to include the Content-Type header in the response with proper Content-Type , e.g: text/plain and try the invocation again. It should work.

If you are not able to change your servlet, you need to configure the ESB to use a default Content Type when the Content Type header is missing. You can find the details on how to do it in http://charithaka.blogspot.sg/2014/07/how-to-enforce-default-http-content.html

Hope this helps!

Thanks and Regards,

Harshana

Comment: Hi, I cannot fix the servlet, is a production servlet from a third party, not under my scope. Although there is not content-type at my browser I can see the message properly "NOK". Is there anyway to treat the response as text/plain by default for this endpoint ?

Comment: In that case you can set a default Content-Type for the response in WSO2 ESB as mentioned in http://charithaka.blogspot.com/2014/07/how-to-enforce-default-http-content.html?m=1